# What is an efficient way to pick out consecutive, same first-letter words from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Taking a list of words, I'd like to pick out consecutive words that start with the same letter. The output should be a list of these pairs.

The following is relatively slow:

```
WikipediaData["alliteration"] // 
TextWords // 
FixedPoint[
  Replace[
    #, 
    {{s___List, w_String, x_String, r___} /; StringTake[w, 1] == StringTake[x, 1] :> 
       {s, {w, x}, x, r}, 
     {s___List, w_String, x_String, r___} :> {s, x, r}, 
     {s___List, w_String} :> {s}}] &, #] &
```

This one is significantly faster:

```
WikipediaData["alliteration"] // 
TextWords // 
Partition[#, 2, 1] & //
Select[#, StringTake[First[#], 1] == StringTake[Last[#], 1] &] &
```

Comment: How about `SequenceCases[TextWords[WikipediaData["alliteration"]], {s1_, s2_} /; StringStartsQ[s2, StringTake[s1, 1]]]`?

Comment: Works, but it doesn't seem particularly efficient - on my system it took over 28.25s, while the methods I showed took 18.98s and 0.125s, respectively. I'm actually curious as to why your method takes so long.

Comment: @Kuba, had forgotten to take care of that lone word - fixed

Comment: @Kuba, Sure, since would handle pairs too, but I'm still looking for performance.

Comment: @Adrian the question is about `{"splendid", "silent", "sun"}` and more. Your method drops `sun` completely.

Comment: @Kuba, fixed the slower method to work with more than two consecutive same-first-letter words.

Comment: @TomD, that works for you?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - it does work, but it's just like @BlacKow 's first version with the `Equal` replaced with `SameQ` which, for the given comparison is the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple version using `SplitBy`.

```
Select[SplitBy[words, StringTake[#, 1] &], Length@# > 1 &]
```

It groups words by the first letter, then picks groups larger than 1. So it solves the more general problem rather than strictly doing pairs.

I don't have no fancy `WikipediaData` on my version, but it seems faster using some randomly generated data.

Comment: Aargh, I was just going to answer myself with this. Oh well, in my answer I was going to provide a solution limiting the grouping to 2, as in the OP, so I suppose I can still put that up.

Comment: That's a great one! Never used `SplitBy`... And about twice faster than my monster

Answer (score 4):

I got faster result using listability of `StringTake` and `Pick` instead of `Select`

```
words = WikipediaData["alliteration"] // TextWords;
{a1, res} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   words // Partition[#, 2, 1] & // 
    Select[#, 
      StringTake[First[#], 1] == StringTake[Last[#], 1] &] &];
a1 (* 0.002902 *)

{b1, res} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   Pick[Partition[#, 2, 1] &@#, 
      Equal @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &@StringTake[#, 1] &@#, True] &@
    words];
b1 (* 0.001041 *)
```

Although it's not in OP's question, it would be nice to handle cases when same first letter words sequence is longer than two (e.g `{"splendid", "silent", "sun"}` as Kuba mentioned). Following code is way slower but handles any length of repeating first letter. It produces list of sublists where every sublist represents sequence of words with the same first letter. For this particular article from Wikipedia the longest sublist has 5 elements.

```
f[{x_, n_, id_}, y_] := If[x == y, {x, n + 1, id + 1}, {y, 1, id + 1}];
{t, sublists} = 
  AbsoluteTiming[
   words[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]]] & /@ Partition[#, 2] &@#[[All, 1, 2]] &@
              Select[#, (#[[1, 1]] == 1 && #[[2, 1]] > 1) || #[[1, 
                    1]] > #[[2, 1]] &] &@Partition[#, 2, 1] &@#[[All, 
            2 ;; -1]] &@FoldList[f, {#[[1]], 1, 1}, #[[2 ;; -1]]] &@
      StringTake[#, 1] &@words];
t
Select[#, Length@# > 2 &] &@sublists
(* 0.011589 *)
```

> ```
> {{"furrow", "followed", "free"}, {"who", "watch", "with", "wild", 
>   "wonder"}, {"beautiful", "birds", "begin"}, {"batter", "bitter", 
>   "but"}, {"bitter", "batter", "better"}, {"Peter", "Piper", "Peter", 
>   "Piper"}, {"Æthelwulf", "Æthelbald", "Æthelberht"}, {"splendid", 
>   "silent", "sun"}, {"Splendid", "Silent", "Sun"}, {"as", "an", 
>   "artistic"}, {"an", "audience\[CloseCurlyQuote]s", 
>   "attention"}, {"them", "to", "the"}, {"twenty-one", "times", 
>   "throughout"}, {"today", "that", "the"}, {"testimony", "to", "the"}}
> ```

Comment: Looks good - just need to understand what's happening there :-)

Comment: @Adrian It obtains the first letter only once per word, and your method does it twice. Also I'm feeding `StringTake[#,1]` with a list  (since it's `Listable`) and you are iterating over partitioned list and applying `StringTake` to every element one at a time.

Comment: That means, for the general case, my second version is still the one to beat.

Comment: @Adrian No. It does different thing. It doesn't return list of pairs. It returns list of sublists where every sublist represents a sequence of words having the same first letter. Some sublists have two elements (that's what you initially wanted), some have more. The longest sublist is `{"who", "watch", "with", "wild", "wonder"}`. So you can't compare these two methods, they are doing different things.

Comment: Actually, what your second one does is different. So you get the crown back.

Answer (score 1):

@wxffles beat me to a `SplitBy` solution, but his version doesn't return a result limited to pairs. So, if that's the requirement, here's one that does. This method is a bit slower for pair-wise collection compared to my second solution in the OP:

```
words = WikipediaData["alliteration"] // TextWords;
SplitBy[words, ToLowerCase[StringTake[#, 1]] &] // 
   Select[#, Length[#] > 1 &] & // 
  If[Length[#] > 2, Partition[#, 2, 1], #] & /@ # & // Level[#, {-2}] &
```

Additionally, most solutions, my own initial ones included, did not ignore case so they missed some groups. The ones provided here do so.

Like @wxffles ', but ignoring case:

```
SplitBy[words, ToLowerCase[StringTake[#, 1]] &] // 
 Select[#, Length[#] > 1 &] &
```

Comment: Why `Identity[#]` instead of `#`?

Comment: Oversight - I'll remove.

Answer (score 0):

Minor variations:

**Using `Characters`:**

```
words = WikipediaData["alliteration"] // TextWords // 
   DeleteCases[_?(StringContainsQ[DigitCharacter])];

Split[words, First@Characters@#1 === First@Characters@#2 &] // 
  Select[Length@# > 1 &]
```

or

```
SplitBy[words, First@*Characters] /. {_} -> Nothing
```

---

*Result*

> {{"as", "a"}, {"Peter", "Piper"}, {"pickled", "peppers"}, {"Irish",
> "It"}, {"important", "ingredient"}, {"Æthelwulf", "Æthelbald",
> "Æthelberht"}, {"direct", "descendants"}, {"Tancred",    "Torhtred"},
> {"Icelandic", "It"}, {"cartoon",    "characters"}, {"identical",
> "initial"}, {"to", "the"}, {"to",    "the"}, {"lazy", "languid",
> "line"}, {"at", "any"}, {"home",    "hot"}, {"is", "in"}, {"stressed",
> "syllable"}, {"to",    "the"}, {"as", "alliterating"}, {"humble",
> "house"}, {"potential",    "power", "play", "picture", "perfect"},
> {"money",    "matters"}, {"rocky", "road"}, {"quick", "question"},
> {"Peter",    "Piper"}, {"pickled", "peppers"}, {"of", "outside"},
> {"same",    "sound"}, {"of", "outside"}, {"to", "the"}, {"brown",
> "blazers"}, {"colour", "co-ordination"}, {"in", "its"}, {"silken",
> "sad"}, {"breeze", "blew"}, {"foam", "flew"}, {"furrow", "followed",
> "free"}, {"stood", "still"}, {"churlish", "chiding"}, {"winter's",
> "wind"}, {"brown", "below"}, {"harvests", "hang"}, {"heavy",
> "head"}, {"Alphabetical", "Africa"}, {"chapter", "consists"}, {"at",
> "all"}, {"written", "with"}, {"Brent", "Bernard"}, {"who", "watch",
> "with", "wild", "wonder"}, {"wide", "window"}, {"beautiful",
> "birds", "begin"}, {"bountiful", "birdseed"}, {"Grey",    "Geese"},
> {"grey", "geese"}, {"Betty", "Botter"}, {"Betty",    "Botter"},
> {"butter", "but"}, {"she", "said"}, {"butter's",    "bitter"}, {"it",
> "in"}, {"make", "my"}, {"batter", "bitter",    "but"}, {"better",
> "butter"}, {"make", "my"}, {"bitter", "batter",    "better"},
> {"Peter", "Piper", "Peter", "Piper"}, {"pickled",    "peppers"},
> {"Peter", "Piper"}, {"pickled", "peppers"}, {"pickled",    "peppers"},
> {"Peter", "Piper"}, {"Poetry", "Poets"}, {"can",    "call"},
> {"splendid", "silent", "sun"}, {"Walt",    "Whitman"}, {"Splendid",
> "Silent", "Sun"}, {"wondered",    "what"}, {"his", "horse"}, {"R.",
> "R."}, {"translation",    "this"}, {"fact", "follows"}, {"an",
> "alliterative"}, {"also",    "add"}, {"to", "the"}, {"harsh", "hard"},
> {"they",    "than"}, {"slippered", "sleep"}, {"lean", "lithe"},
> {"fleet",    "flown"}, {"as", "an", "artistic"}, {"emotional",
> "effect"}, {"and",    "attention-grabbing"}, {"can", "create"},
> {"any",    "attitude"}, {"is", "in"}, {"as", "an"}, {"which", "we"},
> {"our",    "only"}, {"of", "our"}, {"our", "own"}, {"but", "by"},
> {"today",    "that", "the"}, {"truths", "that"}, {"is",
> "inextricably"}, {"to",    "the"}, {"itself", "is"}, {"testimony",
> "to", "the"}, {"have",    "had"}, {"because", "brave"}, {"freedom's",
> "front"}, {"Ronald",    "Reagan"}, {"Vietnam", "Veterans"}, {"new",
> "nation"}, {"to",    "the"}, {"portae", "proficiscere"}, {"and",
> "adds", "an",    "alliterative"},
> {"Μάρθα",
> "Μάρθα"}, {"Martha",    "Martha"},
> {"Martha", "Martha"}, {"Helplessly",    "Hoping"}, {"throughout",
> "the"}, {"stand", "still"}, {"stood",    "still"}, {"Fairyland",
> "Fanfare"}, {"legend", "live",    "life"}, {"all", "alone"}, {"to",
> "the"}, {"lunar",    "lure"}, {"lacking", "lustre"}, {"Anadiplosis",
> "Assonance"}, {"House", "Handbook"}, {"Dumville", "D"}, {"Modern",
> "Memory"}, {"to", "the"}, {"Some", "Suggestive"}, {"E",    "E"},
> {"Indolence", "ISBN"}, {"R", "R"}, {"England",    "External"},
> {"alliterations", "and"}}